# zod - array of different objects

Tags: typescript, zod

Suppose I have the following objects I want to validate with zod. The `page` field can be one of "A" or "B", and depending on the value of `page`, the array inside `form` will be a different set of questions and answers:

```
{
   "page":"A",
   "form":[
      {
         "question":"Basic Info",
         "answer":{
            "Name":"Basic name",
            "Organization or Affiliation (if applicable)":"Big company"
         }
      },
      {
         "question":"I am applying as a ...",
         "answer":[
            "Curator",
            "Service Provider"
         ]
      },
   ]
}

{
   "page":"B",
   "form":[
      {
         "question":"Please provide details of your enquiry or feedback below.",
         "answer":"crash page"
      },
      {
         "question":"What is your preferred contact method?",
         "answer":{
            "Telegram":"telegramID",
            "Email":"lol@lol.com"
         }
      },
      {
         "question":"Please provide contact details for your preferred contact method",
         "answer":"no details about it"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following example schema to validate:

```
const contactSchema = z
  .discriminatedUnion("page", [
    z.object({
      page: z.literal("A"),
      form: z.array(
        // Here goes the questions/answers for A
      )
    }),
    z.object({
      page: z.literal("B"),
      form: z.array(
        // Here goes the questions/answers for B
      )
    }),
  ])
```

How do I enforce arrays of different types of objects?

Comment: Enforce what and how? It's quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the object that you provided, your zod schema looks like the below,

```js
const contactSchema = z.object({
  page: z.union([z.literal("A"), z.literal("B")]),
  form: z.array(
    z.object({
      question: z.string(),
      answer: z
        .record(z.union([z.string(), z.number()]))
        .or(z.array(z.string()))
        .or(z.string()),
    })
  ),
});
```